# broadcast state name Angular js $stateChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-factory

I want to create a factory which should return current state's name, i tried this code inside a controller:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
     $rootScope.tabName  = fromState.name;          
 });
```

but this information is available only if the particular controller is called, i want to make this information available throughout the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it other way around.

```
angular.module('app')
.run(['$state', '$cookies', '$rootScope', function($state, $cookies, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

        $rootScope.tabName  = fromState.name;       
    });
});
```

Rather than putting it in controller, Use it in run method of module which will be called at the time of initialization of application.